# AWS EMR spark submit options - failed

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am trying to run a python job on a EMR spark cluster.

In the spark submit-options i only used the following settings to change the memory:

-- master yarn --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g

However every time i tried to submit the job, it always failed.

May i know how to correct the spark submit options?

And the error log as following:

```
Error: Unrecognized option: --

Usage: spark-submit [options] <app jar | python file | R file> [app arguments]
Usage: spark-submit --kill [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit --status [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit run-example [options] example-class [example args]

Options:
  --master MASTER_URL         spark://host:port, mesos://host:port, yarn,
                              k8s://https://host:port, or local (Default: local[*]).
  --deploy-mode DEPLOY_MODE   Whether to launch the driver program locally ("client") or
                              on one of the worker machines inside the cluster ("cluster")
                              (Default: client).
  --class CLASS_NAME          Your application's main class (for Java / Scala apps).
  --name NAME                 A name of your application.
  --jars JARS                 Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver
                              and executor classpaths.
  --packages                  Comma-separated list of maven coordinates of jars to include
                              on the driver and executor classpaths. Will search the local
                              maven repo, then maven central and any additional remote
                              repositories given by --repositories. The format for the
                              coordinates should be groupId:artifactId:version.
  --exclude-packages          Comma-separated list of groupId:artifactId, to exclude while
                              resolving the dependencies provided in --packages to avoid
                              dependency conflicts.
  --repositories              Comma-separated list of additional remote repositories to
                              search for the maven coordinates given with --packages.
  --py-files PY_FILES         Comma-separated list of .zip, .egg, or .py files to place
                              on the PYTHONPATH for Python apps.
  --files FILES               Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working
                              directory of each executor. File paths of these files
                              in executors can be accessed via SparkFiles.get(fileName).

  --conf PROP=VALUE           Arbitrary Spark configuration property.
  --properties-file FILE      Path to a file from which to load extra properties. If not
                              specified, this will look for conf/spark-defaults.conf.

  --driver-memory MEM         Memory for driver (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 1024M).
  --driver-java-options       Extra Java optionCommand exiting with ret '1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a space between `--` and `master`.

Try `--master` instead of `-- master`.